# How store password in keychain utilities in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

How can i store and restore the password of my application to and from the keychain utilities in ipad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving Email/Password to Keychain in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247912/saving-email-password-to-keychain-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one third party library which helps us to store and retrive the passwords to keychain.

[Here is the link to download it.](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to talk to the Security framework to make things with the keychain. However, this framework is still in C and not very convenient to use. That is why I like using the objective-C wrapper EMKeychain http://extendmac.com/EMKeychain/ .