# How Long Does Keychain Data Last?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

From what I've read, storing data in keychain will persist even after uninstalling your app. And since it depends on the provisioning profile used, we can be assured that the data stored is secured. However, I'm not sure how long the data will last in the keychain. Will it be deleted after a month? Can the user delete it by force? Will it be deleted if I change my provisioning profile for my app? Will it be deleted if the profile expires? Can someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: after you reset your device from settings. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350072/saving-login-credentials-xcode/12350243#12350243)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, will it get reset if you update to another ios version or it will only be reset if the user manually resets on device settings?

Comment: Also, if i change my provisioning profile, does it mean that i won't be able to access the data i stored in the keychain? (sorry i don't know much about provisioning profiles)

Comment: Don't store real sensitive data in the keychain; on jailbroken devices, it's wide open as plain text (google "keychain dumper").

Comment: @user1681701 only if user manually resets on device settings. For other part see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313715/does-renewing-a-provisioning-profile-affect-keychain-access-when-i-submit-an-app