# KeychainItemWrapper in iOS6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I'm using KeyChainItemWeapper.m in my app project to save the nickname and the password. In iOS7 works perfectly but in iOS 6.0, 6.1 it crashes. The error is:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain], /Users/KeychainItemWrapper.m:328
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ea2012 0x1c5ae7e 0x1ea1e78 0x1919665 0xe785a 0xe6bf0 0x1479b6 0x14848f 0x11bb0bc 0x1c6e705 0xdcb2c0 0xdcb258 0xe8c021 0xe8c57f 0xe8b6e8 0xdfacef 0xdfaf02 0xdd8d4a 0xdca698 0x2f77df9 0x2f77ad0 0x1e17bf5 0x1e17962 0x1e48bb6 0x1e47f44 0x1e47e1b 0x2f767e3 0x2f76668 0xdc7ffc 0x15270d 0x356d725 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

This code is on the app crash:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"100PrimerosLogin" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:disp_pasa.token forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
[keychain setObject:nick forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
[keychain setObject:(__bridge id)(kSecClassGenericPassword) forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[keychain setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];
```

The nickname is the iphone mac and the password an alphanumeric code.

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749160/saving-in-keychainitemwrapper-crashes-for-password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to save the Auth Token in Keychain, then save the value for kSecAttrService key:
like:

```
[keychain setObject:@"YourAppNameDecription" forKey: (__bridge id)kSecAttrService];
```

Add save above value also in keychain when saving token and other fields.

This will resolves your crashing issue.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I tried it but I didn't put the value above saving token.