# How to store a password in iOS 7 using ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I'm working on an app for iOS 7 and am using ARC. I am using a web service so users have to log into the web service with a username and password. I'm know it's not good to just store the username and password as is so I would like to use keychain to store the username and password.

After doing some research it seems like people suggest using `KeychainItemWrapper` however that is not compatible with ARC. How can I store passwords using keychain in iOS 7 using ARC? Any help and guidelines would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247912/saving-email-password-to-keychain-in-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following:

```
+ (void)keyChainSaveKey:(NSString *)key data:(id)data
{
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:key];
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
    [keychainQuery setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, NULL);
}

+ (id)keyChainLoadKey:(NSString *)key
{
    id ret = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:key];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    [keychainQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    CFDataRef keyData = NULL;
    if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&keyData) == noErr) {
        @try {
            ret = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(__bridge NSData *)keyData];
        }
        @catch (NSException *e) {
            //NS Log(@"Unarchive of %@ failed: %@", service, e);
        }
        @finally {}
    }
    if (keyData) CFRelease(keyData);
    return ret;
}

+ (void)keyChainDeleteKey:(NSString *)service
{
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
}

//helper
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)getKeychainQuery:(NSString *)key
{
    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge id)kSecClass,
            key, (__bridge id)kSecAttrService,
            key, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount,
            (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible,
            nil];
}
```

You might need to

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
```

I don't remember where I found this code... so I can't give credit :(