# Is this a good practise to store and get passwords from the Keychain in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, passwords, keychain, password-encryption

I want to store and retrieve passwords from the Keychain on an iDevice. I searched on the internet and there are a lot of options and things that can be done. I would say there are to many for a beginner with Keychain ;). Apple's own code for this is from 2010 and not really helpful anymore. I found this piece of code (the ARC ready one): [Saving Email/Password to Keychain in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247912/saving-email-password-to-keychain-in-ios)

Now is my question before I connect this class to the rest of my code, is this a good practice? Is this how Apple wants it and how I am supposed to interact with the Keychain or is there something much better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

That is the storing of passwords in the keychain is good practice as that is part what it is provided for.